# After getting four reopen votes, why did it not reopen my question? Confused

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-reopen

My [one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358008/display-bounty-expire-time-in-the-bounty-tab) got four reopen votes. More than one day goes down, but still it did not reopen my question. What was wrong?

[Question link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358008/display-bounty-expire-time-in-the-bounty-tab)

**Someone explain, please**

I followed the question *[How long does it take for a question to appear in the reopen queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209143/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-question-to-appear-in-the-reopen-queue)*

Comment: Can you link the question that was closed and voted for reopening? Also AFAIK you need to get 5 reopen votes.

Comment: @Mark Kirby question [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358008/display-bounty-expire-time-in-the-bounty-tab)

Comment: I can't see the reopen votes here but from the time line I can see 2 or 3 reopen votes at some point but you need 5 for it to be reopened. As it has only been a day since it got closed, all you can do is have some patience and wait and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/358008/timeline) of the question shows the [Reopen review queue item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/76505) ended up leaving the question closed. The reopen votes are still active, but somebody needs to go the question itself in order to reopen it; since the last activity on the question is 15 days ago, users are not likely to visit it anymore.

Comment: I not clear about _Reopen review queue item_ .. but would you tell me my question will reopen or not ?

Comment: Not unless someone else thinks it should ve reopened. You need 5 votes to reopen. Improving your question is the best way to make that happen.